# What is the most modern mobile browser possible to install into an old Android 1.5, 1.6?

Tags: applications, browser, compatibility, 1.6-donut, 1.5-cupcake

I got in my hand an old Sony Ericsson Xperia X10 mini pro from 12 years ago and this is a quite nice, beautiful, and outdated Android. I do have however interest in seeing how modern mobile apps behave on this device.

The default Android browser simply doesn't open any page anymore, but I got it rooted and installed the first Opera version (6.x) I found on APK Mirror.

Does anyone know which exact version is the most modern browser that this Android 1.6 device can run?

Comment: Based on the data from Wikipedia this phone has only 256 MB RAM, which is a very very small amount. So even if you find a working web browser just opening the web browser will most likely require more RAM than you have. I would assume that app you test simly crash directly at startup or a little time later just because of missing RAM.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Cross-checking [the Wikipedia entry for Android web browsers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category:Android_web_browsers) with APK mirroring sites, looks like **only [Opera 12.1](https://www.apkmirror.com/apk/opera-software-asa/opera/opera-12-1-release/) is supported on Android 1.6**.

For references:

| Browser | Android version |
| --- | --- |
| [Brave Private Web Browser](https://www.apkmirror.com/apk/brave-software/brave-browser/#variants) | Android 4.1+ |
| [CM Browser](https://www.apkmirror.com/apk/cheetah-mobile-communications/cm-browser-adblock-fast-download-privacy/cm-browser-adblock-fast-download-privacy-5-21-15-release/cm-browser-adblock-fast-download-privacy-5-21-15-android-apk-download/) | Android 4.0+ |
| [Cliqz](https://m.apkpure.com/cliqz-%E2%80%93-the-privacy-browser/com.cliqz.browser/download/10355-APK) | Android 4.4+ |
| [Ghostery Privacy Browser](https://www.apkmirror.com/apk/ghostery-inc/ghostery-privacy-browser/#variants) | Android 4.1+ |
| [Dolphin Browser](https://www.apkmirror.com/apk/dolphin-browser/dolphin-browser-dolphin-browser/dolphin-browser-dolphin-browser-8-5-1-3-release/) | Android 2.0.1+ |
| [Dolphine Zero](https://www.apkmirror.com/apk/dolphin-browser/dolphin-zero/dolphin-zero-1-0-0-2-release/dolphin-zero-1-0-0-android-apk-download/) | Android 2.2+ |
| [Lunascape](https://m.apkpure.com/lunascape-web-browser/jp.co.lunascape.android.ilunascape/download/30-APK) | Android 2.2+ |
| [Firefox](https://www.apkmirror.com/apk/mozilla/firefox/#variants) | Android 2.0+ |
| [Firefox Lite](https://www.apkmirror.com/apk/mozilla/firefox-rocket-fast-and-lightweight-web-browser/firefox-rocket-beta-fast-and-lightweight-0-8-1455-release/firefox-rocket-beta-fast-and-lightweight-0-8-1455-android-apk-download/) | Android 5.0 |
| [Google Chrome](https://www.apkmirror.com/apk/google-inc/chrome/#variants) | Android 4.0+ |
| [Kiwi Browser](https://www.apkmirror.com/apk/geometry-ou/kiwi-browser-fast-quiet/#variants) | Android 4.1+ |
| [Lunascape](https://m.apkpure.com/lunascape-web-browser/jp.co.lunascape.android.ilunascape/download/30-APK) | Android 2.2+ |
| [Mercury](https://m.apkpure.com/mercury-browser-for-android/com.ilegendsoft.mercury/download/50-APK) | Android 2.3.4+ |
| [Microsoft Edge](https://www.apkmirror.com/apk/microsoft-corporation/microsoft-edge/#variants) | Android 4.4+ |
| [Naver Whale](https://www.apkmirror.com/apk/naver-corp/naver-whale-browser/#variants) | Android 5.0+ |
| [Opera Browser](https://www.apkmirror.com/apk/opera-software-asa/opera/#variants) | **Android 1.5+ (10.1.1011151737), Android 1.6+ (12.1)** |
| [Opera Mini](https://www.apkmirror.com/apk/opera-software-asa/opera-mini/#variants) | Android 2.3+ |
| [Samsung Internet Browser](https://www.apkmirror.com/apk/samsung-electronics-co-ltd/samsung-internet-for-android/#variants) | Android 4.4+ |
| [Sleipnir](https://apkpure.com/sleipnir-mobile-web-browser/jp.co.fenrir.android.sleipnir/download/3052881-APK) | Android 4.0.3+ |
| [UC Browser](https://www.apkmirror.com/apk/ucweb-singapore-pte-ltd/uc-browser/#variants) | Android 2.1+ |
| [Vivaldi Browser](https://www.apkmirror.com/apk/vivaldi-technologies/vivaldi-browser-beta/vivaldi-browser-beta-2-7-1624-163-release/) | Android 5.0+ |
| [Waterfox](https://www.apkmirror.com/apk/waterfox-ltd/waterfox-privacy-web-browser-free-and-open/#variants) | Android 4.1+ |
| [Yandex Browser](https://www.apkmirror.com/apk/yandex-apps/yandex-browser/#variants) | Android 4.1+ |

---

Note however that despite the possibility to install Opera 12.1, it's still not guaranteed that most modern websites will open due to HTTPS-only and [only supporting TLS 1.2 and above](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/227394/should-i-disable-tls-1-0-and-tls-1-1-support-on-my-web-servers), which is only supported since Android 4.4+.

Comment: I am not sure if the TLS version of web browsers is really an issue. as this only affects the Android Java API but web browsers are usually written in C/C++ and most likely contain their own SSL/TLS library.

Comment: Another point is that a small APK size can imply that the app is just a skin over the Android framework WebView which prior to Android 5.0 was only updated with a ROM update. An old embeddable engine for Android 4.0+ [results in a APK of about 20MB](https://github.com/crosswalk-project/crosswalk-website-v2/blob/master/public/documentation/about/faq.md)